# React Fetch sending binary file to .Net Core WebAPI endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send a binary file, with some parameters (Filename, related Id etc) to my .Net Core 3 WebAPI endpoint.

My endpoint looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, Route("/api/attachment")]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] AttachmentCreateRequest request)
{
```

The model I am trying to get back, and convert into my POCO, is:

```
 public class AttachmentCreateRequest
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Guid TransactionId { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
```

When I send a request, Chrome Tools indicates this being sent:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryXrahZqoiAk4lYBgv Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="eBay_ Order details.pdf"
>   Content-Type: application/pdf
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryXrahZqoiAk4lYBgv Content-Disposition: form-data; name="transactionId"
>
> 762505fe-81bd-4b07-9456-cf7f0bb70efb
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryXrahZqoiAk4lYBgv Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"
>
> test
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryXrahZqoiAk4lYBgv--

The fields I am trying to send are the file, named 'file', a transactionId, which seems to be visible in that data above, and a field called 'description', which I set as 'test'.

But a break point on by method, shows null:

[image]

Why would my file parameter be null?

Details about my app:
I use a generic Fetch method to make all my calls. In the call I make, 'isBinary' is true.

```
const fetchData = ({ method = 'GET', URL, data = {}, isBinary = false}) => {
  // Force the content type.
  console.log("FetchData got request:", data)
  const contentType = isBinary ? undefined : 'application/json'
  const header = {
    'Content-Type': contentType,
    Accept: contentType,
  };
  console.log("content type will be", contentType)

  // If we have a bearer token (User seems to be signed in), add it to the header.
  const userIsAuthenticated = Auth.isAuthenticated();
  if (userIsAuthenticated) {
    header.Authorization = `Bearer ${Auth.token()}`;
  }

  // Create the config that will be used for the fetch.
  let config = {
    method,
    headers: header,
  };

  // If this is anything but a GET, set the body to hold the data we're posting.
  if (method !== 'GET' && method !== 'DELETE') {
    if(isBinary)
    {
      console.log("IsBinary.. on't stringify")
      config = Object.assign({}, config, { body: data });
    }
    else
    {
        const stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log("Body is: ", stringified)

        config = Object.assign({}, config, { body: stringified });
    }
  }

  console.log("Fetch: ", config)
  // Use the browser api, fetch, to make the call.

  return fetch(URL, config)
    .then((raw) => {
      return raw;
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.timeEnd(`fetchExecutionTime ${URL}`)
      console.log(`An error has occured while calling the API. ${e}`);
    });
};
```

The 'data' field is defined:

```
let data = new FormData() 
    data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)
    data.append('transactionId', this.state.transaction.id)
    data.append('description', 'test')
    console.log("Data now", data)
```

.. where 'selectedFile' is from the form control where the file is selected. I 'append' the three properties that my POCO object expects.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is imputable to form tag configuration.

It seems that it considers correctly information and type received from view, but view doesn't send correctly all data.

Can you share sketch relativa form tag?

Comment: Sorry, Dario. I'm not quite sure what that means.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to more clear. Where do you call the Create action from? I think it is set by the form you use. I think about this because "FromForm" is indicated in the action parameter, is my deduction correct? When the action parameters are not correctly valued by the starting form, in some cases it does not give an error, but simply does not pass information.

Comment: OK, does this help? I've added my client side calling code.